# How to make git ignore files without . ("dot") character

Tags: git

For example, I have these files:

```
sorting
generateData
tmp.c
tmp.txt
```

I want to ignore two files "sorting" and "generateData".

I tried adding "[^.]+", "*[^.]*" into .gitignore file but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little work you can get that effect for any particular repo.

If you put

```
*
!*.*
```

at the top of a `.gitignore`, that will have the effect of accepting all and only files with a dot.  This does what you want but also bypasses all lower-precedence files.

So if you put the above at the top of `.git/info/exclude` it'll have the effect of ignoring everything without a dot *and also* shutting off your personal excludes (in `~/.config/git/ignore` by default).  You can kludge around that easily enough, but it'll never be pretty.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading the manual: `man gitignore`.

You have the wrong syntax and you actually can't do what you're asking since it's not a regular expression engine. Try adding the specific files you want to ignore instead:

```
sorting
generateData
```